# UIImagepicker not displaying in IPad Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

Having problem with my application, I seem to be new in ios. My project contains a **rootViewAppDelegate**,**rootViewController**,and **cameraViewController**.

My **rootViewcontroller** has a Menu type code implemented in it that when a button is pressed it goes to **cameraViewController**.My **cameraViewController** contains a **UIImagepicker**.

In following a tutorial in the net about **UIImagePicker** in IPAD, it says there that I should paste some part of the code in the delegate. So I pasted it in the **rootViewAppDelegate**. When I run the project. Nothing is displaying in the **cameraViewController**. Did I miss something wrong? Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not having all the details, what I think is happening is the following:

- The rootViewAppDelegate is not the delegate of your UIImagepicker - and you probably don't want to set it to be one as it's the "App's" delegate
- So what you are seeing happening is that your UIImagePicker has no object to trigger a delegate on

What probably needs to be done is to use your cameraViewController as the UIImagePicker delegate - to do so you need to go into your: cameraViewController and set it as being a follower of the UIImagePickerDelegate protocol:

```
@interface cameraViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
```

Then within your UIImagePicker you need to set the delegate to be the cameraViewController - you can do this in code if you have a source file for your UIImagePicker by saying something like:

```
[self setDelegate:myCameraViewController];
```

OR in InterfaceBuilder/Storyboard, you need to connect the delegate property of the UIImagePicker to the cameraViewController.

This will then know that the cameraViewController is the delegate of the UIPicker and trigger it appropriately.

Comment: So I'm going to make another class for the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate?

Comment: Not necessarily - another class, e.g. your cameraViewController should be able to become your delegate for the UIPicker. The UIPickerControllerDelegate is itself part of the iOS APIs. - see this example: https://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/01/ ; also the delegate reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html

Comment: There is no need. Your cameraViewController can act as a delegate of the UIImagePickerController; so it needs to contain the methods that are required for it to be a UIImagePickerControllerDelegate - e.g. -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info

Comment: The example code is in the link posted before - agilewarrior:  http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/01